# node_save does not save body content

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm trying to create a node using PHP. The below code works fine until I use any language code other than 'LANGUAGE_NONE'.

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'recipe';
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->uid = 1;
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$node->title = $item['title'];
$node->body[$node->language][0]['value']= $item['description'];
$node->body[$node->language][0]['format']= 'plain_text';      
node_save($node);
```

If I use "en" instead of "LANGUAGE_NONE" then the node is created without any field being populated. That is, there is only a title; the body is blank.

Locale module is enabled and i18n is installed and enabled.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to set the language of the fields.

```
$node->language = 'en';
$field_langcode = field_language('node', $node, 'body');
$node->body[$field_langcode][0]['value']   = $body_text;
$node->body[$field_langcode][0]['summary'] = text_summary($body_text);
$node->body[$field_langcode][0]['format']  = filter_default_format();
```

See this comment (https://drupal.org/comment/5464106#comment-5464106) for more info.